# Create GUI components with states

Tags: java, swing

I was asking about the right way to make a component that holds some state. Like a Jbutton that saves a color in it, or a list item that saves a certain object. So when those GUI components fire an event I can use the saved states to do something with it.

My way was like that:

1- Make a subclass of the required component, like a subclass from Jbutton.

2- Make a Listener for this new subclass : in the listener check if the event source is the subclass, convert it then use the stored data.

Example:

```
class ColorButton extends JButton
{
    static class Listener implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            Object source = actionEvent.getSource();
            if( source.getClass() == ColorButton.class)
            {
                ColorButton t = (ColorButton) source;
                t.getComponent().setBackground(t.getColor());
            }
        }
    }


    //states i want to be saved
    private Color c;
    private Component comp;

    ColorButton(Component comp, Color c) {
        setColorChanger(comp, c);
    }

    /*   ......
         ......
         rest of constructors added with those additions
         ......
    */
    private void  setColorChanger(Component comp, Color c)
    {
        this.comp = comp;
        this.c = c;
    }

    Color getColor() {
        return c;
    }

    Component getComponent() {
        return comp;
    }

}
```

And I use it this way:

```
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        ColorButton.Listener l = new ColorButton.Listener();
        JButton b = new ColorButton("Blue", panel, Color.BLUE);
        JButton r = new ColorButton("Red", panel, Color.RED);
        r.addActionListener(l);
        b.addActionListener(l);
        panel.add(b);
        panel.add(r);
        add(panel);
```

So I was wondering if this way is okay or what, I feel it is very boring to make this for every component that should hold a certain states, is there a better way?

Comment: You need to word your question better. =)

Comment: Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if you're looking for ways to improve existing working code.

Comment: Create a GUI model to hold state.  Your GUI components can reference the GUI model to find out what they need to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a better way. Every single component object should have its own separate ActionListener, so that you don't have to check `if( source.getClass() == ColorButton.class)`, and you can *directly access* the fields of the component by name, without having to go through the `source` at all. For that to work, you have to use a non-static inner class, or an anonymous inner class. That `if` statement is a very old-fashioned and non-OOP way of doing things.

In fact, the component object itself can be *its own* ActionListener - but that style only allows you to have one ActionListener, and is a bit less well-organised.

Comment: so I should just remove the if line and use this listener with only this type of class isn't this right? I just thought of putting this check so if I accidentally assigned other object to this listener I wont get a runtime error.

Comment: so I should call it like that `r.addActionListener(r.new Listener());` and just directly change backgorund in the `actionPerformed` method?

Comment: @Doggynub yes, that's what I mean

Answer (score 0):

The better way is dependent on what kind of state you want to hold and what use you want to make of it.  Without thinking that through so that you can state it, it isn't possible to make an overall plan for a better way to do it.  Is setting color the only thing you want to do?  Do you need to mix regular JButtons with ColorButtons in your application?

Comment: how would it differ what use i want to make of it or the thing i am going to hold in it :) I really can't pros and cons there.

Comment: For example, in your current example, you are calling getColor on your button.  I think your instinct is right, any time you have to use instanceof to drive logic, it tends to indicate a better way is possible.  Do you also want to call getFont?  getSize?  Do the things you want to do all have to do with appearance?  Are they all things the button/component can do for itself?  You asked for a better way, so it is logical to ask "A better way to do what?"  You haven't defined that well yet.

Comment: Well, the only thing I want to do is save one extra object in a gui component so when it is clicked later I know what to do, it have got to do nothing with the appearence, it maybe like a list item (carrying names for products) when clicked it shows me the profile of that productlike id, name etc... Just to know what product to show I need to save some type of int in that list item so when it is clicked I know which product profile to show.